# Read first n lines of a huge file from remote server using bash command

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scp

I want to read first n lines of a huge file which resides at a **different server**. I was using scp to copy the file:

```
sshpass -p $password scp $username@$server:$path_to_file "$content_file"
```

But, I just want first few lines from the file. If the file is huge, I end-up downloading the whole file first and then I read first n lines using `head` command. I tried replacing `head` with `scp` but that did not help me. Please suggest the right way.

Comment: Is the file exposed only via. ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following command to output remote result to local.

```
ssh hostA head srcfile > destfile
```

or use the following to output local output to remote.

```
ssh hostA 'head > destfile' < srcfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a hack. But if you're limited to the scp utility, and your local host is unix-like, you can do this:

```
scp user@host:/some/file /dev/stdout | head > destfile
```

This causes `scp` to begin downloading the remote file, writing it to scp's standard output. You can pipe that output into `head` or another utility which processes the contents of the file.

Comment: This is one hell of a hack and I am loving it!